# how to pass xml nodes from xsl php

Tags: xml, xslt

Currently I have this php:

```
$xmlstrQs = '<QSHotel></QSHotel>';
$xmlqs = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstrQs);

$xmlqs->addChild('Occupancies');
$xmlqs->Occupancies->AddChild('Occupancy');
$xmlqs->Occupancies->Occupancy->AddChild('Rooms', 1);       
$xmlqs->Occupancies->Occupancy->AddChild('Adults', 2);
$xmlqs->Occupancies->Occupancy->AddChild('Childrens');      

$myXmlqs = $xmlqs->asXML();
$myXmlqs = str_replace('<?xml version="1.0"?>', '', $myXmlqs);

$xslt->setParameter( '', 'qsHotel', $myXmlqs);
```

I need to send it as xml or whatever and walk it in xslt:

should reach the following way to xslt:

```
<xsl:variable name="qsHotel">
  <QSHotel>
    <Occupancy>
      <Rooms>1</Rooms>
      <Adults>2</Adults>
      <Childrens/>
    </Occupancy>
  </QSHotel>
</xsl:variable>
```

And then cross it as a node

```
<xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($qsHotel)/QSHotel/Occupancies/Occupancy">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass XML into an XSL stylesheet using an XSL parameter. XSL parameters only accept strings.

You can get XML into an XSL stylesheet in two ways;

1. The XML source document.
2. Within the XSLT, use the `document()` function to load an XML file.

Comment: You have an example? please!

Comment: Do you want an example of 1 or 2?

Comment: 2. please, for testing!

Comment: I found this but does not work:

PHP function:

 function getNodeSet() {
  $xml = '
      <Occupancies>
        <Occupancy>
          <Rooms>1</Rooms>
          <Adults>2</Adults>
          <Childrens />
        </Occupancy>
      </Occupancies>';
  
  $doc = new DOMDocument;
     $doc->loadXml($xml);
    return $doc;
 }  

Get in xslt:

<xsl:for-each select="php:function('getNodeSet')" />

Comment: I've added another answer to show using the `document()` function in an XSL stylesheet.

Comment: U have another example?? non-complex

Comment: I can't think how to make it any simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to use PHP to get an XML file into an XSL stylesheet using the `document()` function...

```
<?php

$xml = mini_transform('<doc/>', 'foo.xsl');
echo("<xmp>$xml</xmp>");

// Mini-transform.
function mini_transform($str_xml, $file_xsl) {
  $xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
  $xslt->importStylesheet(new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($file_xsl)));
  return $xslt->transformToXml(new SimpleXMLElement($str_xml));
}

?>
```

**foo.xsl**

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="doc">
    <result>
      <xsl:copy-of select="document('bar.xml')/*"/>
    </result>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**bar.xml**

```
<bar bish="234">
  <bosh/>
</bar>
```

**The result**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<result>
  <bar bish="234">
    <bosh/>
  </bar>
</result>
```